# Video streaming in react-native using custom API

Tags: django, react-native, expo, react-native-video

I'm working on a react-native app using expo-av to show videos, and whne I put in source the uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4', from google samples, it acutally works, but if I try to put a uri for a video contained in my django media folder, the following error occur:
**The server is not correctly configured. - The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11850 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain".**

How can I solve?
Thank you

Comment: How are you serving the video file from django media folder? What's the absolute URL you are passing to the `Video` component?